# Jest Unit Test modify nextState in middleware

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

So, I am trying to unit tests middleware, where the middleware logic is run after `next(action)`. But as mockStore doesn't run reducers, the nextState is always same as original state. Is there a way I can simulate reducer while using mockStore?

Comment: so do you want to test it in integration into Redux? since it's possible to compose test like it's ordinary function. and when you are testing if middleware is executed on `next` you are actually testing redux itself(and I believe you don't really to)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was, instead of dispatching the action, I called the middleware methods with `(state, nextState)` and verified the behavior.